# Скачивание файла на сайте

Tags: файлы, веб-программирование

Добрый день, сейчас заканчиваю работу над одним сайтом, и возник вопрос: как организовать доступ к видеофайлам, т.е. на одной из страниц есть ссылка на видео файл (примерно 700 мегабайт), как лучше сделать форму с капчей, после заполнения которой пользователь получит файл или просто ссылку на файл без формы?

Дело в том что некоторые люди заявляют, что если просто делать ссылки на такие файлы, то будут дёргать боты эти файлы и что это не совсем правильно, на сколько обосновано такое утверждение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылки лучше давать просто так, но, их можно защищать, к примеру, не давать файлы тем, у кого реферер не Ваш сайт, или привязывать ссылки к IP адресам.

Comment: как я понимаю в конфигах Apashe или nginx  можно  прописать настройки типа если юзер не ссайта изначально на страницу перешёл, то тогда не выдавать, так?

Comment: Верно, можно в конфигах прописать, но надежнее все таки будет вязать к IP.

Answer (score 0):

Советую просто сделать ссылки на файл, либо просто разрешить скачивать зарегистрированным пользователям.